# Ban URLs of last 60 minutes in varnish?

Tags: caching, varnish

Is it possible to ban the last 60 minutes of URLs which were input to Varnish?

The background is the following:

I have a large cache of more than 150.000 objects. An error occurred, so all sites which have been cached in the last 60 minutes should be banned.
But I do not want to ban all the pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the Date header in the ban expression.

Given a date header like `Tue, 22 Jul 2014 13:19:17 GMT`, you can use: `varnishadm ban obj.http.date ~ "22 Jul 2014 13:"` to ban any objects added to the cache in the 13th hour of July 22nd 2014.

This isn't exactly smooth or accurate, but it will get the job done.